# Arduino SD Card reading text file function

Tags: c, string, arduino

Please let me know I make a function for reading TXT file by using Arduino Mega2560 and SD Card.
But the function works only first time when execute but second time it is not working, I tried most but could not succeed. Code is attached and TXT file is also attached.

And sometimes it returns garbage value like 235, 124 and other values like that while I made its return type is bool.

"Here is txt file Data driverid.txt"
"
2741#8785#3922#5805#6774#2911#9611#1334#1616#4004#8152#9572#3927#7114#1865#7806#8784#5968#1624#4507#4248#7930#6625#3193#3180#1065#6327#6925#3785#6931#6951#7629#9123#7124#2853#8565#8938#2938#2790#4495#4896#8030#8744#7768#1726#9891#8995#7827#2903#2568#7815#9159#3519#3735#2283#9660#2871#2180#6984#8450#5680#1216#3384#8224#5256#5146#6928#7568#7148#5733#6554#4775#6752#9525#6714#9748#5906#9240#9752#1659#1257#9221#3014#2986#6402#3876#2458#7042#2704#5756#6991#4417#4098#1977#5059#9462#7549#5126#2630#7284#9673#3172#7511#3839#7584#2531#5389#5288#4340#1075#8321#8027#8036#6316#4106#4913#9480#4429#7909#5159#1995#2049#7991#9308#2824#7904#1539#2878#3683#7524#8849#7352#7132#7409#6284#1002#8731#8248#1968#6036#2418#4196#1882#6716#5483#2382#7439#7660#9026#8910#2128#4566#9371#2887#5945#3934#2632#5639#9357#7562#2874#4518#1606#8372#3960#8096#7977#4169#2682#9495#7901#2693#1083#4626#7585#3058#6970#5355#8478#2112#4867#5644#9076#3297#6547#4485#1636#6757#1990#4456#4381#6552#2360#7686#7313#1239#5835#4046#1162#4516#4366#8673#7074#3394#7792#3019#9553#1633#8405#8265#3980#4198#2315#6975#1270#1064#3259#9671#8958#7567#1522#2420#4227#8481#5920#9680#7604#2025#8394#1088#4582#8299#9543#5511#7690#8081#2375#5347#9721#6042#7254#8597#2466#1437#1161#8160#1371#6318#7963#1377#7211#5210#6850#3395#6450#7674#1802#2435#2396#9598#4882#6251#6312#2806#5672#9385#9842#5201#1867#3590#7824#5936#7577#6624#3781#9293#3241#4869#1108#5739#9201#8635#9258#1971#2497#9111#1998#1173#3513#2178#2096#7522#3974#5534#6028#5420#7867#7790#2640#7243#2174#7337#9926#1332#3720#5056#8109#9723#3713#9131#4057#1563#5663#5105#7485#3540#9183#5192#9867#5873#9376#1996#1922#7687#1576#6283#2098#8969#3371#6891#3805#6288#6260#2684#4187#8728#1142#5530#8087#8881#7155#7277#6516#4226#8934#8389#1227#4604#6169#9544#4676#1765#6209#6079#6909#2609#7035#2989#7554#6452#6801#1966#3052#6486#3739#1266#8857#5880#5340#2076#6726#4963#2532#4705#8600#4885#7091#2987#9794#9976#4077#6254#1913#3678#1104#7311#8059#5221#2063#2448#8533#5327#8818#4806#1148#3861#7900#4349#3454#8906#4528#7612#1840#1124#3073#4397#3064#2546#9702#9641#3929#3748#3803#5985#9725#4268#5677#2173#6460#5600#1207#3425#8585#4095#7481#2879#6532#9909#6050#6235#7680#1770#1072#6555#8896#2383#3289#2898#8148#5902#4753#6796#3635#7980#4770#9884#9693#1741#8020#8080#6615#1854#7052#3278#7918#6173#3360#7955#7855#2509#4435#7563#3132#5788#1159#3339#9140#7088#9010#9922#8625#8598#7399#2377#4071#5564#2241#9253#6803#7418#1240#4096#4966#7347#9454#4411#3097#6324#9726#5574#5931#1592#3593#7292#8571#9655#7615#2841#5591#1892#8662#7075#7749#5244#1007#3048#6125#5129#3821#8766#1194#9256#5140#7932#4514#8071#4822#3614#6446#5075#5068#1399#1627#8275#1021#5760#5778#6151#8546#9864#9823#4702#6644#2931#4170#2285#6948#9147#8827#4293#9696#5840#7139#4647#5103#4630#8703#3835#1425#4974#8936#5401#4685#4868#1958#9746#8201#8221#2398#9247#3993#2683#5779#8724#1273#8200#2694#6604#5088#6831#1557#7250#5930#7109#1398#6183#5913#2321#3555#4385#9176#6101#3925#7280#9157#5624#2116#4213#8767#7635#2369#6341#9695#3190#5970#8987#7864#4164#3114#4637#2117#7941#7500#1062#8357#3417#3165#3345#4756#8496#8638#2246#3264#5194#9045#6585#6739#3502#3160#3684#4751#5167#9027#5267#8091#6781#8549#6352#6114#7769#4448#7516#3075#8712#6599#2975#9782#6037#9510#1066#7107#8722#4159#3992#7037#5413#9200#8568#5183#7187#7967#8004#9862#9595#2864#8176#9902#5937#8756#8441#1748#9040#6379#6977#4726#6301#2988#8759#8709#7131#9399#5274#6305#2041#7830#5371#9373#7336#6468#4445#1536#1609#7476#7623#8228#6560#1049#2209#4534#2750#4803#1571#2732#5789#6027#6986#4143#1342#5464#8468#2298#5678#8656#8743#4396#3255#2789#2582#4278#9436#3696#6693#4375#2250#7081#6166#5361#6859#2154#7477#4660#5031#6475#5360#7755#1763#1390#8079#2484#4715#8069#6033#6201#4951#3841#4861#6190#3885#5367#6833#1042#6279#6827#8411#5157#2481#4972#4667#3429#2274#5987#9133#5753#3130#1603#4327#5028#6296#3613#6915#3325#8022#6713#3415#5793#3314#7771#5081#5029#1450#6651#4591#2677#3379#9064#7641#3331#3705#8983#6610#6231#1439#7117#6247#4110#4023#5375#5202#6415#5127#8141#6725#8692#9127#4132#4739#3291#3806#8329#5617#3437#7926#3559#2685#1749#5230#4809#2556#9727#9067#8733#7078#1830#8871#4677#8957#5714#6782#4815#5662#4369#7653#3498#4714#7227#7274#6870#9223#2543#6618#9592#4254#2981#1962#5034#9446#9584#1527#3393#1269#9989#5654#5311#1799#3405#4124#3469#5608#4434#9731#7537#7812#8615#6372#3809#7929#1737#5478#5336#6921#2567#4301#3849#1321#3154#9683#8734#5521#4881#5213#6832#3420#1373#8049#3202#7393#6179#1209#1667#1376#7913#7960#6115#2170#6606#7391#3691#9413#2530#4816#9007#9686#9416#3286#9947#5784#3213#2156#3605#8880#7539#7819#4312#2764#9166#3620#6976#1413#6689#8061#6695#1851#5280#7614#4847#5681#2761#9382#5998#4305#7976#4791#9039#8233#9263#5679#4236#4746#5024#7609#6411#7047#3558#1696#1610#9378#6134#6697#9783#5939#1693#4733#5223#3326#4584#9855#6510#4538#8285#9848#3432#3349#7574#3682#3536#7556#9493#1689#1991#2149#2939#1814#3275#1105#4617#9283#3060#3793#7579#1068#5323#1881#8883#5390#6066#1024#2176#4370#2835#5943#5166#4316#5243#5792#2572#4309#9901#7969#5546#5870#9608#5037#4379#8902#3511#4432#9074#7740#1637#3958#1012#8024#6922#9634#7252#2008#5797#5651#3363#9318#5606#8554#7923#2232#9952#9245#9058#5516#9350#3931#8191#2261#8406#2907#4492#8298#6791#3476#6150#1316#2772#9908#7435#2433#4800#6654#6872#4005#2258#7116#6583#2191#8072#4512#4062#6647#8474#7202#3142#8374#6168#6454#7268#7758#4047#1661#9053#8746#2231#9451#6014#3617#8904#4116#4968#9146#1771#6572#2574#2272#9445#5712#8612#1707#6963#9262#4468#8561#2844#9547#5782#8104#5035#3358#9284#5350#7413#7459#3772#5447#9729#3709#8770#4977#3077#7325#6021#6255#6123#6250#7907#7316#1337#5154#4475#9342#9609#8819#5110#2540#9698#3346#3369#2656#1915#9310#6736#6086#3978#2452#5364#4250#1608#3440#5944#4064#8953#2942#2464#4933#9834#7392#9519#6003#2304#2680#9288#2569#1669#3245#2547#2690#9118#1324#5107#8203#2748#7647#6273#2143#7833#9622#8519#4078#4372#6636#5373#4712#8447#7724#7761#7783#6159#9426#9888#5337#4897#5950#4129#4145#3786#6146#5786#5501#9151#8365#7008#2221#1368#4509#4415#2055#4042#5842#8269#7199#2010#1233#3158#6794#7534#1037#2000#9251#1281#2889#6699#2980#7799#3133#1350#8861#7129#2736#7813#8240#4244#6907#2757#4946#4825#6696#4817#3386#3353#4177#2796#6410#4133#2424#8439#3152#1868#8383#2275#6145#8220#2505#5233#4140#8580#1036#5737#3206#8851#8307#6482#4190#8243#5915#4799#4735#6750#4231#7924#5671#8875#4410#7334#9670#9637#7366#7791#3646#3518#8463#4041#4588#9427#5594#4184#5575#2062#9920#2475#8804#8339#5935#9122#1734#1844#8364#3564#1230#4068#3221#9600#8384#2771#2109#8545#9291#1395#3182#7258#6531#8787#8717#3472#9513#5952#2662#4258#4845#9071#5446#3546#3506#1208#1479#4189#6632#2842#8645#8948#5253#2227#3816#1382#5900#7627#4937#7944#4598#1464#4383#8186#8944#5352#5962#5265#5197#5252#7442#3080#7719#7970#2550#9789#1517#9056#5385#5633#1010#2803#3918#1684#4220#3005#1163#9314#8607#1656#2890#3938#2499#6334#6553#4192#3561#9630#8701#4983#8324#4884#5072#1556#4563#3838#4493#9555#8973#7939#1614#4286#4655#3672#5705#9821#1314#9388#6919#7441#9624#9459#2940#4431#4783#5852#2731#3625#7104#2425#8931#7555#4325#5757#4367#3762#8211#9999#7605#8551#2639#3798#6591#2910#4903#4793#6205#2730#7370#1225#5130#4996#2469#3299#6512#3270#4262#4927#4675#9340#7349#1347#3232#8658#4691#6764#4590#3205#2324#4601#3161#1355#3252#2253#2091#9086#2302#2291#3939#5215#6715#3529#4716#3468#9327#7184#1219#9733#9571#8034#1093#
"

`

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

bool verify = false;
String myString = "";
String type = "AZ-7773#";
String ID = "Vehicle ID";
File myFile;

bool verifydata(String typeID, String ID) {
  Serial.print("SCAN DATA:");
  Serial.println(typeID);
  Serial.println(ID + ".txt below Scan Data ");
  if (ID.equals("Driver ID"))
  {
    Serial.println("OPEN DRIVER ID");
    SDcardinitialize();
    myFile = SD.open("driverid.txt");
  }
  else if(ID.equals("Vehicle ID"))
  {
    Serial.println("OPEN TRUCK ID");
    SDcardinitialize();
    myFile = SD.open("truckid.txt");
  }

  if (myFile)
  {
    Serial.println(ID + ".txt in myFile");

    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available())
    {
      myString = myFile.readString();
      if (myString.indexOf(typeID) >= 0)
      {
        Serial.println("FOUND");
        myString = "";
        myFile.close();
        return 1;
      }
      else
      {       
        Serial.println("DOES NOT FOUND");
        myString = "";
        myFile.close();
        return 0;
      }

    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();   
  }
  else
  {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening " + ID + ".txt");
  }
}

void SDcardinitialize()
{
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(10)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SDcardinitialize();
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
verify = verifydata(type , ID);
if(verify == 0){
  Serial.print("Not Verify ");
  Serial.println(verify);
  }else{
    Serial.print("Verified ");
    Serial.println(verify);
    }
delay(4000);
}
```

`

Comment: You probably have warnings from the compiler - there are places where `verifydata()` doesn't return a value, and it should. Second, I would `SD.begin()` just once, in `setup`, like the documents and examples show: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD

Comment: aMike Thanks for helping I added return statement where empty spaces and set SD.begin() only in setup(). But problem is reading txt file which have numbers followed by #, I want to search particular number in txt file, I tried many attempts but not succesful, any hint will highly appreciated.

Comment: So the txt file looks like one big long line?  No line-feed or carriage-return characters?  Maybe `readString` actually tried reading it all and overwrote something else in memory? (buffer overflow) Maybe try `readStringUntil` and tell it to break on `#`?  https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamreadstringuntil/

Comment: I tried it but not working, how slice one big long line into small lines and how to read line by line?

Comment: It's strange that `readStringUntil` wouldn't chop the line apart... maybe it also needs to see line-endings?  The other option is to read character-by-character, saving them into a buffer, and stop when you see the delimiter, then compare. Are the IDs in the SD files always numbers? Then you could try `parseInt()` which will get the next number from the stream... then you would compare integers instead of strings.

Comment: find() solved the problem.